# Remove defined string from list - python

Tags: python, list, indexing, split

```
foo = '/input/directory/'
faa = ['/input/directory/file1.txt', '/input/directory/file2.txt']
```

I need to remove the directory name (i.e foo) from my list (faa) and the file extension, leaving just

```
bar = ['file1', 'file2']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`map`](https://devdocs.io/python~2.7/library/functions#map)

```
bar = map(lambda x: '.'.join(x.replace(foo, '').split('.')[:-1]), faa)
```

Comment: This is slightly incorrect - what if the file contains a dot in its name? The first lambda should thus be modified.

Edit: with the new shortened code - the slice of the split() should not be just [0] :) ... Edit 2: you should probably use rsplit(___, 1)[0] instead.

Comment: @plamut Agreed, fixed now

Answer (score 1):

try;

```
>>> [x.replace(foo, '').split('.')[0] for x in faa]
['file1', 'file2']
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe:

```
bar = [elem.replace(foo, '').rsplit('.', 1)[0] for elem in faa]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foo = '/input/directory/'
faa = ['/input/directory/file1.txt', '/input/directory/file2.txt']

import os.path

bar = [os.path.splitext(path.replace(foo, ''))[0]
       for path in faa]
print(bar)
```

Or without foo:

```
faa = ['/input/directory/file1.txt', '/input/directory/file2.txt']

from os.path import basename, splitext
bar = [splitext(basename(path))[0]
       for path in faa]
print(bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
import os

foo = '/input/directory/'
faa = ['/input/directory/file1.txt', '/input/directory/file2.txt', '/not/matching/foo/file3.txt']   

faa = [os.path.splitext(os.path.split(f)[1])[0] if f.startswith(foo) else f for f in faa]   
print faa
```

This would give you the following list:

```
['file1', 'file2', '/not/matching/foo/file3.txt']
```

If you always want the filename then:

```
import os

foo = '/input/directory/'
faa = ['/input/directory/file1.txt', '/input/directory/file2.txt', '/not/matching/foo/file3.txt']   

faa = [os.path.splitext(os.path.split(f)[1])[0] for f in faa]   
print faa
```

Giving:

```
['file1', 'file2', 'file3']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
import re
foo = '/input/directory/'
faa = ['/input/directory/file1.txt', '/input/directory/file2.txt']

# Use a regular expression to match '<foo>someFileName<.fileExtension>'
faa = [re.sub(r'^%s(.*)\.\w+$' % foo, '\g<1>', elem) for elem in faa]

# faa => ['file1', 'file2']
```

Comment: `foo = '/input/directory'` <- the string should be quoted

Comment: Ah yes, you're right (I copy-pasted it from the OP's question).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re` module and `re.findall` to achieve that with positive look behind `(?<=)` for your `foo` string and positive look ahead for `extension` with anchor to the end of the string:

```
res = [re.findall('(?<={}).+(?=[.].*$)'.format(foo), elem)[0] for elem in faa]

print(res)
['file1', 'file2']
```

*Note*: You could check that `regex` expression with [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/)